# How do I redirect to a static HTML page from disk when clicking a link on an ASP.net website?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I was asked to make a downloads page for our company intranet. They want a folder on the server in which they can drop files for others to download. The way I did this was to create an ASP.net website which looks at that folder and creates list of hyperlinks for every file in that folder. Every one of this hyperlinks triggers the function to present that file for download to the user.

Here's the problem. Some of those files are static HTML pages and the users want to navigate to those pages instead of downloading them. So I used the following code

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathToFile);
if (file.Extension.Equals(".htm") || file.Extension.Equals(".htmls"))
    Response.Redirect("file:///" + file.FullName);
else { /* run the download code */}
```

The download part works fine. Clicking on an html link does nothing and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Try redirecting to the web address of the file (http://...) the files must be addressable within the URL space of the website. The file:// schema only works on your own machine, not across the network. You are effectively asking the user to find that file on their own machine - and of course it's not there.

Comment: Why not create a genuine html link in your page that shows the folder contents?